# Drawing broken Path in Android

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, path, android-canvas

I'm trying to create the graph of: 1 / (x Squared - 1 )

As you can see, the graph looks nice:
[image]

The code below draws the graph above. But I don't want the vertical asymptotes to show.

```
path.moveTo(valx, valy);
path.quadTo(x, y, middle2, middle);
path.lineTo(x, y); // I think this is what causes the vertical asymptotes to show
canvas.drawPath(path, points);
path.reset();
```

By looking at the line path.lineTo above, I can see the path is connecting points with a line. That is
why the vertical asymptotes are drawn.

The idea I have implemented is as follows In pseudo code:

```
//split the x axis into regions and compute a limiting value for each region
Boolean drawMe = false;
//region1: those x values less than the first asymptote = -1
if(Float.compare(x values , first asymptote = -1) < 0 && Float.compare(absolute value of
(Math.abs(x value) - Math.abs(first asymptote) , 0.01f ) > 0)drawMe = true

//region2: those x values between both asymptotes which are -1 and 1:
if(Float.compare(x values , first asymptote) > 0 && Float.compare(x values , second asymptote) < 0
   && Float.compare(absolute value of(Math.abs(x value) - Math.abs(first asymptote) , 0.01f) > 0
   && Float.compare(absolute value of(Math.abs(x value) - Math.abs(second asymptote) , 0.01f) > 0)
   drawMe = true;

//region3: those x values greater than the second asymptote = 1:
if(Float.compare(x values , second asymptote) > 0 && Float.compare(absolute value of(Math.abs(x value) - Math.abs(second asymptote) , 0.01f) > 0 ) drawMe = true;

if(drawMe){
path.moveTo(valx, valy);
path.quadTo(x, y, middle2, middle);
path.lineTo(x, y); // I think this is what causes the vertical asymptotes to show
canvas.drawPath(path, points);
path.reset();
}
```

However, splitting the x axis into regions is drawing the same exact thing again.
I need to find a way to stop the asymptotes from drawing, and I think the big problem lies
into the line of code:  path.lineTo

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows:

- Do split the x axis into regions based on where the vertical asymptotes lie
- as points are added to the path, check that the x value of the point does not lie within
  a certain threshold of the vertical asymptote
- DONT reset the path and DONT draw the path. Wait for the for loop to add all the points
  except those that fall within a certain threshold of the vertical asymptotes
- By not adding those points to the path, the path will be broken up and show the correct graph
- AFTER the for loop finishes adding the points to the path, draw the path

  **First** close the path:
  path.close();
  **Then:**
  canvas.drawPath(path, points);

*The logic was correct*, except that I was not transforming the x values and vertical asymptote values as I did for the rest of the points. That is why , the path was being drawn exactly the same all over again.

See the pictures, I was even able to dashed the asymptotes:

[image]